# How to unset passed by reference variable in Laravel chunk?

Tags: php, laravel, closures

I'm working to transfer old-DB data to new-tab in laravel and I am using chunk to overcome memory leak. but when I pass the external variable in chuck Closure by use($var) its update and I display it after chunk completed.but when I reset that variable or null that variable it can't update. That display previous value.

To unset passed by reference variable I used below thinks:

```
unset($output);
$output = null;
$output = array();
```

Above code not reset the $output

```
$output = array(
        "exceptional_queries" => array(),
        "total_row" => 0,
        "inserted_row" => 0
    );

// Table 1

$f_package = $con->table('old_table')->orderBy('id');

$f_package->chunk(50, function ($package) use (&$output) {

        $total_data = count($package);
        $output['total_row'] += $total_data;
        foreach ($package as $data) {
            try {
                $insert = [
                    ......
                ];
                //Insert Data
                $result  = DB::table('new_table')->insert($insert);
                if ($result) {
                    $output['inserted_row']++;
                }
            } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                // Catch query exception & store it in array
                if ($exception instanceof Illuminate\Database\QueryException) {
                    $output['exceptional_queries'][] = $exception->getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
    });

   echo "-> $table: ".$output['inserted_row']." row inserted out of ".$output['total_row']." \n";
    if (count($output['exceptional_queries'])) {
        echo "- ".count($output['exceptional_queries'])." row has QueryException! \n";
    }

    unset($output);
    $output = null;
    $output = array(
        "exceptional_queries" => array(),
        "total_row" => 0,
        "inserted_row" => 0
    );

//Table 2

 Repeat above things............
```

On Table-2 its Display exception of Table-1 & Table-2 both. Basically, the **$output** is not reset or unset. so it occurs.

How can I reset it?

Thank You.

Comment: do you know that you are unsetting  this out of the both loop ?

Comment: yes, @GauravGupta I know.

Comment: from above code as much i can understand you are inserting single row at a time , you can insert array together it'll reduce your db connection

Comment: yes, you are right @GauravGupta

Comment: one more thing why do you need to reset $output ?

Comment: it's not reset the content of previously added data in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193519/discussion-between-gaurav-gupta-and-farhan-shaikh).